# Awarding of bounty failed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty

To whom it may concern:

I had a bounty out on [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/intermediate-coding-representation-for-levenshtein-distance).  I accepted an answer before the bounty expired and awarded the 50 points.  But then the bounty actually expired and I got a notice that the answer had been auto-selected and only the autoselect-25 points had been awarded.

I'm really darn sure I checked the check-mark as I said.  I'm sure it's possible that I forgot, but due to the low volume of bounties on the site and its newness, I'll trust my memory for now.

Comment: And I didn't get my Benefactor badge either!!!

Comment: Did you *both* accept the answer *and* award the bounty? These are two separate actions. The check-mark refers to accepting an answer; the red "+50" blob refers to giving the bounty.

Comment: Is that new?  I believe it used to be that accepting an answer awarded the bounty.

Comment: If so, I think that feature needs to be reviewed.  Even for new users who never used the old way, I'd think the difference isn't clear.  I didn't know the +50 image was clickable.

Comment: I don't think we can do anything about the way it works, and I personally don't think it is confusing.

Comment: I don't think it is a new feature. Besides, occasionally it's nice that we can use these features separately. For example, [I have awarded the bounty to one answer and accepted another](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/191/bounded-cardinality-bounded-frequency-set-cover-hardness-of-approximation).

Comment: Bounties on MathOverflow seems to work in a different way (because they use SE 1.0).  Therefore, those who are familiar with how they work on MathOverflow should be careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct -- accepting an answer and bounty award are two different actions now.

This is documented in the /faq (parent) and on the blog.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/